# Devise: how to use another mail view when user requests email change ( instead of the default )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, confirmation, devise-confirmable

1. Logged in user changes email under users#registration
2. User receives email to confirm this email change

The email send in step 2 is exactly the same as when a user registers for the first time and has to confirm his email for the first time.

Is there a way to use another email view So I can more customise the text like "you requested your email to be changed, please click below link.. " instead of using the default message.

This would be a cosmetic but much wanted feature in our application.

Anyway to do this? Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial task, actualy you need to overwrite [this devise method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L92-L100) inside your model:

```
  def send_confirmation_instructions
    if reconfirmation_required?
      self.confirmation_token = nil if reconfirmation_required?
      @reconfirmation_required = false

      ensure_confirmation_token!

      opts = pending_reconfirmation? ? { :to => unconfirmed_email } : { }
      send_devise_notification(:reconfirmation_instructions, opts)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Then you need to extend [`Devise::Mailer`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb) to add method `reconfirmation_instructions`

And finally you need to create view `app/views/devise/mailer/reconfirmation_instructions.html.erb`

Comment: Great thank you for sharing. Is it possible to somehow extract all the "Devise specific" hacks from the user model to 1 central location to have things more organised? Answer accepted though its perfect

Comment: Only getting a undefined method `ensure_confirmation_token!' for #<User:0x007fdb11cbfb58>